# Getting error on API call: Attachment resolution failure for transaction hash

Tags: corda

Please note that the below works perfectly fine on my local Ubuntu VM with 3 local nodes (PartyA, PartyB, and Notary); it only happens with this setup:

1. I have 2 VM's on GCP
2. Both are running nodes that I got from TestNet
3. Both nodes are upgraded to OS 4.1 and running the same CordApps
4. Each VM has its SpringBoot webserver
5. For both nodes I'm able to access my API end points (for example `api/me` shows my nodes's identity).
6. I get the error when I call the following API (again this all works locally with local nodes): `curl --request POST 'http://XXXX:XXXX/api/my_token/issue?amount=100&partyName=O=XXXX,L=London,C=GB' --header "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: can you add the stack trace you're getting?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/adelRestom/54f6eb668025b1e55992c861aa8ea9d0

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running into a known issue on Corda 4.1: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-3110

If your Cordapp has no Corda artifacts in the jar it will not be loaded into the node. You can work around this issue by adding a "DummyContract" into the module which will ensure the node loads the Cordapp jar. An example of this can be seen in the Tokens SDK: https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/V1/modules/money/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/money/internal/DummyContract.kt

Comment: Adding a dummy contract didn't solve the problem, and btw I realized I already had a contract (`ExampleEvolvableTokenTypeContract` from the tokens sdk Java template).